# What are the inclusions among these topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

We have two bases of topologies on $\mathbb{R}$:

> $B_1 = \{[a, b] : a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$,
>
> $B_2 = \{[a, b] : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

List all inclusions among $\mathscr{T_1}$, $\mathscr{T_2}$ and the usual topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, including whether any inclusions are strict. Justify your assertions.

I know that $\mathscr{T_1}$ and $\mathscr{T_2}$ generate the same topologies but how these related to the inclusions?

Can anyone give me some hints on this question?

What are the inclusions of these topologies?

Comment: Jiaying Wang, I am flagging all your posts that you are editing in your attempt to hide your questions, stop this.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Every interval $(a,b)$ can be written as a union of intervals of the form $[p,q]$, with $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$. That shows $\mathscr T \subset \mathscr T_1$. For the reverse inclusion, ask yourself whether $[a,b]\in\mathscr{T}$.
- Given an interval $[a,b]$ whose endpoints are irrational, can you write it as a union of intervals of the form $[p,q]$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$?